Does obtaining a long-term visa in one EU country cancel residence permit in another EU country?
My spouse is a resident of Cyprus and I am a resident of Germany. She wants to stay in Germany for 5 months in a row, but keep Cyprus residency and return back afterwards. Regular Schengen travel visa has a limit of 90 days so this means we need to apply for family reunification. Does it affect Cyprus residency in any way? Is it considered bad to apply for family reunification but then not getting residency and moving back afterwards?

Does this answer your question? Can I have 2 EU residency permits at once?


She wants to stay in Germany for 5 months in a row, but keep Cyprus residency and return back afterwards.
Does it affect Cyprus residency in any way?

If you have a Temporary Residence Permit: yes.
A Cyprus Temporary Residence Permit (issued for 1 year and is renewable annually up to 5 years) will be cancelled after an absence of 3 months.


I have a residence permit and I will travel abroad. How can I return to Cyprus?
If you hold a valid temporary residence permit, you can re-enter Cyprus by presenting the permit and valid passport, provided that you have not stayed abroad for more than three months.


Sources:

FAQ - Residence permits/ documents | Civil Registry and Migration Department - Cyprus

